# Best way to integrate data from Firebase and REST API in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am building a stock portfolio app and am facing an issue with data flow management. I have 3 collections for users, transactions and accounts in firebase. I use a stream provider to fetch data for transactions from firebase into the flutter app. In addition, I have a service that fetches and saves the current stock data(price, percentage change, volume, etc) from a REST API into a list within the flutter app. I wanted to understand what is the best way to manage data from both these endpoints and be able to show them on the screen, update them whenever they get updated.

If

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having a proxy server in the middle to manage your communications for :

1. Managing Firebase collections
2. Fetching and save current stock price data
3. Load balancing and proxying.

The reasons for suggesting the same are:

1. Decoupling of data flow into microservices. Your Flutter app should just manage UI and hit the necessary api endpoints. Your logic for resolving client requests should only exist on the server. This will reduce your app bundle size and help with horizontal-scaling should the traffic increase.
2. Can cache common responses by applying Redis on this server.
3. Better application of security rules for both Firebase and REST API compared to Flutter application
4. Say tomorrow you wish to add more API services, this will just mean adding those endpoints on this server and hitting them with your Frontend application.

Having such an architecture will reduce the dependency of the entire stack on each independent service (be it your Flutter app or your Firebase backend).

Comment: Thanks, Ankit for the detailed Answer. I have no experience writing code for a proxy server but was able to find quite a lot of material on youtube to enable me to do that. Before I venture into that direction, I wanted to understand if having a proxy server that receives data from these multiple endpoints and provides my flutter app with a single API source to fetch data, is the only way to go about this problem? If not could you please suggest a short term fix for 

1. Having in-app functions that run and collect data in variables and then flutter UI displays them.

Comment: 2. Every time the database is updated the in-app functions run again to perform all the calculations and API fetches.